# Fix my Fat Fingers

Tags: code-golf, keyboard, hardware

## Code Golf Challenge

I have an isdue, my fingrrs are fat and I freqintly jave an isdue of ty[ing one keystrpke to the right on my kryboard.

I'm afraid the isdue is getyng worse anf worsr as time goes on.

Sopn every keystrpke I make wil; be shiftrd pne to the right!

Befpre then I'd like a program (or functipn) to autp shift every keystrpke back to the left one.

I'll make sure to take my tome typong the rest of tjis chal;enge so as not to cause anu confudion!

---

## Objective:

Write a program or function that takes an input of one of the following green keys on a standard QWERTY keyboard and returns the character of the key one to the left of it.[image]

---

## Conditions:

•You may assume that the person running this program is using a QWERTY keyboard like the one pictured above.

•Input and Output are both case-insensitive, you may use any case (or a mixture of case combinations) for this challenge and you can also assume all input will be in one case if desired.

•If your language has no way of allowing a user to input the return key for some reason you may ignore that one keystroke for this

•This challenge is just for the default values of the keys, for example if the `4` key is pressed you can assume it will always be `4` and never `$`

•You can assume only the green keys will ever be pressed.

---

## Example `Input` -> `Output`:

`S` -> `a`
`4` -> `3`
`=` -> `-`
`[` -> `p`

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the program with the shortest bytecount wins!

Comment: Could you provide testcases?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Certaimly! I'll edit tjat in now@

Comment: Did you mean `]` -> `[` ?

Comment: @shooqie fixrd!

Comment: Do we need to provide functionality for backspaces?

Comment: @Okx No thats npt a green key@ (in my imsge)

Comment: [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92986/corrcey-my-soellign)

Comment: You might not care, but here's an interesting piece of trivia: this is an ANSI keyboard layout. Note the backslash above the Enter key; in contrast to an ISO keyboard, in which the backslash button is to the left of Z. (It's also American, but that's easier to identify!)

Comment: @Doddy ah nice to know. I was wondering why the Enter key was cut in half.

Comment: I can see no green keys on the image, only black keys overlaid with green circles.

Comment: @Doddy On my work keyboard the `|\` key is used twice for some reason.. Left of the `Z` as you said, but another one between the `'"` and `ENTER ↵`, which I usually use. Didn't even knew one was right of the `Z` before.. xD

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, <s>76 71</s> 69 bytes

```
->a{"`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./"[/.#{a}/][0]}
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), <s>87</s> <s>83</s> 69 bytes

```perl6
{[Q"`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'
zxcvbnm,./".comb].&{%(.[1..*]Z=>$_)}{$_}}
```

```perl6
{~Q"`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'
zxcvbnm,./".match(/.)>$_/)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#y61UUEtTsP1fXReolGBoZGxiamZuYWmga1tYnlpUUlmamV8QHRuTWJySlp6RlZ1jrc5VVZFclpSXq6Onr6SXm1iSnKGhr6dppxKvr1n7vzixUiFNQalYyZoLyjRBMG0RzGgl6/8A)

Wondering if there's a way to encode that hard-coded string to something shorter...

*(Stole [G B's regex idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111135/14880) for -14 bytes.)*

Comment: Maybe if we had `$"` the ranges could save a few chars

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
ØD”`1¦ṭØqż“[]\“;'¶“,./“0-=”Fṡ2UZy
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394hsujhrkJhoeWPdy59vCMwqN7HjXMiY6NAZLW6oe2ASkdPX0gaaBrC1Tn9nDnQqPQqMr/QJFiE9tooNDh9v8A)

#### How it works

```
ØD”`1¦ṭØqż“[]\“;'¶“,./“0-=”Fṡ2UZy  Main link. Argument: s (string)

ØD                                 Digits; yield "0123456789".
  ”`1|                             Replace '0' with a backtick.
       Øq                          Qwerty; yield
                                   ["qwertyuiop", "asdfghjkl", "zxcvbnm"].
      ṭ                            Tack; add "`123456789" as the last element of
                                   the qwerty array.
          “[]\“;'¶“,./“0-=”        Yield ["[]\\", ";'\n", "0-="].
         ż                         Zip; combine the strings of the array to the
                                   left with the corresponding strings of the array
                                   to the right, yielding an array of string pairs.
                           F       Flatten, yielding a string.
                            ṡ2     Obtain all overlapping pairs of characters.
                              U    Upend; reverse each pair.
                               Z   Zip, yielding a pair of strings.
                                y  Translate the input s according to the generated
                                   replacement table.
```

Comment: I don't know Jelly, can you add an explanation of your code? I'm curious how you got away without typing a string literal of the whole keyboard

Comment: I didn't have the time yet, but I'll add an explanation asap.

Comment: Done. I also golfed it a bit.

Comment: `Øq` nifty! I like this, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <s>85</s> 78 bytes:

```
lambda x,k="`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm<>?":k[k.‌​find(x)-1]
```

Comment: You can pass the string as optional parameter, using 1 lambda : `lambda x,k="1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm<>?":k[k.find(x)-1]` to reduce few bytes

Comment: Good point, I'll add that.

Comment: I think you need a backtick to be to the left of 1.

Comment: @xnor Right, fixed that.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <strike>53</strike> 51 bytes

```
T`1-90\-=QW\ERTYUI\OP[]\\ASDF-HJ-L;'¶ZXCVBNM,./`\`o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@SYKhraRCjaxsYHuMaFBIZ6hnjHxAdGxPjGOzipuvhpetjrX5oW1SEc5iTn6@Onn5CTEL@//@GRsYmpmbmFpYGurbhEG1gXUA97h5e3kA9XHAdAA)

A simple transliteration shifting every character 1 position backwards. Everything from `1` to `/` is the original character set, while the following part is the new set, using `o` to indicate the Other set.

`H` and `L` are special character classes for transliteration in retina (respectively mapping to Hex digits and uppercase Letters), but fortunately they occur on the keyboard inside alfabetically ordered sequences (`FGH` and `JKL`), so we can avoid escaping them by putting them in ranges and gain like that 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 76 bytes

```python
s="1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm<>?"
dict(zip(s,'`'+s)).get
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NctZE4FAAADgZ37Fzr5UyCQ5ihj3fd9as5Ikamu2cvz6PPneP0tFsaO7l6sOAiXIhlQngaOHJguZCkyJYhpiAWP5nBPzUqFYKuPxhK/WMELb/WrX7vY2/eFo2hzM1E5jeWgtjmtE5icNYwxTEhffPAoMYBMA/18WePVt0vAb2Z6vnRAKrjfr/ng6FQaRj/G6ELdaq8Ns5PsmZTklmfCpTUJgZIDFGlz8Aw)

Makes a dictionary that takes each key to the one to its left by zipping the character string with its shifted version. The bottom line is the function, the top one is a definition.

Using `translate` to create a mapping gave a longer solution. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NctZE4FAAADgZ37Fzr5UyCQ5ihj3fd9as5Ikamu2cvz6PPneP0tFsaO7l6sOAiXIhlQngaOHJguZCkyJYhpiAWP5nBPzUqFYKuPxhK/WMELb/WrX7vY2/eFo2hzM1E5jeWgtjmtE5icNYwxTEhffPAoMYBMA/18WePVt0vAb2Z6vnRAKrjfr/ng6FQaRj/G6ELdaq8Ns5PsmZTklmfCpTUJgZIDFGlz8Aw)

```python
lambda s:s.translate("';"*22+"_0__9`12345678_LM-<>_\\VXSWDFGUHJKNBIO=EARYCQZT\nP][___"*4)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>57</s> <s>54</s> 51 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @nmjcman101 for using `hxVp` instead of what I had for the multiline keyboard*

```
i`¬190-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./<esc>/<C-r>a
hxVp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@5@ZcGiNoaWBrm1heWpRSWVpZn5BdGxMYnFKWnpGVnaOtXpVRXJZUl6ujp6@tL5QIldGRVjB////owE)

`<esc>` is `0x1b` and `<c-r>` is `0x12`

Note: this doesn't not support the enter key

Contains unprintables, so here's the hexdump

```
00000000: 6960 ac31 3930 2d3d 7177 6572 7479 7569  i`.190-=qwertyui
00000010: 6f70 5b5d 5c61 7364 6667 686a 6b6c 3b27  op[]\asdfghjkl;'
00000020: 7a78 6376 626e 6d2c 2e2f 1b2f 1261 0a68  zxcvbnm,././.a.h
00000030: 7856 70                                  xVp
```

#### Explanation

Most of the program generates the keyboard. `i` enters insert mode and every character following it is printed to the buffer. But there is a small quirk here, `¬19` inserts characters between 1 and 9.

The program exits insert mode at the `<esc>`. And then here `/<c-r>a` it searches for the argument in the buffer. This brings the cursor on top of the character it found.

```
h                  " move the cursor to the left
 x                 " delete this character
  Vp               " select this line and replace it with the deleted character
```

Comment: I'm not 100%, but I think instead of `hylHVGp` you can do what @DJMcMayhem did in the motorcycle question like `hxVp`.  I'm not sure why you put the `G` in there, isn't it all one line?  Also `dhVp` would work.

Comment: @nmjcman101 Ah yes, I must have kept the `G` since when the keyboard used to be multiline. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 109 bytes

```
void f(char i){std::string k="`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./";std::cout<<k[k.find(i)-1];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#HcxJDoIwGEDhfU/R4IKSCIqzFLwIkFhbCr@FVpkcCGdH4tt@yZsWoHnZiQyHYJq2zlh1Qag3ILAkvGA1BmdoWhEEM4LOsYqsq7/Z7vaH4@m8dqPnK6vbTwfmEadJwhoh8@KuSmon@vvm/U1XS29l0f@Cm64NQxUrT4IWBBzXT@mIUMVAEwcNCM9JYhe2Q9E4TT8)

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, 70 bytes

I doubt that it could get any shorter than this...

```
Input Str1
"`1234567890-=QWERTYUIOP[]\ASDFGHJKL;'ZXCVBNM,./
sub(Ans,inString(Ans,Str1)-1,1
```

P.S. The two-byte tokens are `Str1`, `` ` ``, `\`, `sub(`, and `inString(`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>56</strike> 42 bytes

```
;D=Dv ·q i"[]\\",A i";'",22 +",./")Dg1nDbU
```

#### Explanation

```
;D=Dv ·q i"[]\\",A i";'",22 +",./")Dg1nDbU

;D=D                                        // Shortcut for QWERTY (with newlines and spaces), assigning to variable D
    v                                       // Setting D to lowercase
      ·q                                    // Joining D into an array with no spaces or newlines
        i"[]\\",A                          // Inserting "[]\" into index 10 (A)
                   i";'",22                 // Inserting ";'" into index 22
                           +",./"           // Appending ",./"
                                  Dg        // Returns the character at index:
                                    1n      //    -1+
                                       DbU  //     Index of U (the input)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@2/tYutSpnBoe6FCplJ0bEyMko6hAZBpra6kY2SkoK2ko6evpOmSbpjnkhT6/79StBIA)

Comment: This one is cool, can you add an explanation?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 82 bytes

```
$k="1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\asdfghjkl;'
zxcvbnm,./";$k[$k.IndexOf((read-host))-1]
```

The Enter key is supported, but cannot be tested with `Read-Host` because the act of hitting enter with no value returns nothing in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

```
c=>(s=".,mnbvcxz\n';lkjhgfdsa\\][poiuytrewq=-0987654321`")[s.indexOf(c)+1]
```

Since `/` isn't in my string, `indexOf` returns `-1`, which when incremented causes `.` to be output. 93 bytes to process a string:

```
s=>s.replace(/./g,c=>s[s.indexOf(c)+1],s="><mnbvcxz\n';lkjhgfdsa\\][poiuytrewq=-0987654321`")
```

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for spotting that I'd accidentally shifted those three keys. I've unshifted them now.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 99 bytes

```java
c->{String r="`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./";return r.charAt(r.indexOf(c)-1);}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY/BbsIwDEDvfIXFpYm0ZmNjGyjqpH3A2IFji0RIU0hp3S5JOxjqt3dh5TpVsmXZftKzc9GKsKoV5umxl4WwFj6ExssEQKNTJhNSweraAsiDMCDJUCj3s86nD@uE0xJWgBBBL8O3y9oZjXsw0XQ7e3yaP7@8LpYPYfT1rYw7N7qq402SCJtm@0N@LHiQ4M9Jtjss79j9lBvlGoNg2FX17ohhGlN1@syIpOGM8q7ng7hudoUX3/xtpVMo/fVk0McbEHQ4fX22TpWsahyr/coVSJBJEtiA/j3yPzEfJaJRIh4lErwh3aTrfwE)

```java
c->{                // Method with character as both parameter and return-type
  String r="`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./";
                    //  Literal String of the qwerty keyboard layout of the challenge
  return r.charAt(  //  Return the character at the following index:
    r.indexOf(c)    //   The index of the input character
    -1);            //   -1 to shift it to the left
}                   // End of method
```

Comment: I give up. I was trying to do it with regex, but I miserably fail with some special characters... ``c->"`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./".replaceAll("(?s).*(.)"+c+".*","$1")``.

Answer (score 1):

### [GNU sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), 72 + 1(r flag) = 73 bytes

```
s:$:`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./:
s:(.).*(.)\1.*:\2:
```

The return key can't be tested, because sed by design splits the input using `\n` as the delimiter and then runs the script as many times as there are lines.

**Test run:** continuous input-output pair (when done press Ctrl + D or Ctrl + C)

```sh
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ sed -rf shift_key.sed
s
a
4
3
=
-
a
\
1
`
\
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 50 bytes

```
'`žhÀ"-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./"JDÀ‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@ecHRfxuEGJV3bwvLUopLK0sz8gujYmJjE4pS09Iys7Bxr9Zi8qorksqS8XB09fSUvl8MNjxoW/v@fkZqTk69Qnl@UkwIA)

Explanation:

```
'`                                                  # 1 char string: `
  žh                                                # Push numbers 0123456789
    À                                               # Rotated 1 left (123456890)
     "-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'\nzxcvbnm,./"      # Push string literal
                                              J     # Join all elements pushed to the stack to one string
                                               D    # Duplicate
                                                À   # Rotate 1 left
                                                 ‡  # Transliterate: a.get(b.indexOf(input))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 56 bytes

```
@K"`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'
zxcvbnm,./"txK
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40K%22%601234567890-%3Dqwertyuiop%5B%5D%5C%5Casdfghjkl%3B%27%0Azxcvbnm%2C.%2F%22txK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22s%22%0A%224%22%0A%22%3D%22%0A%22%5B%22&debug=0).