# Keyboard Encryption

Tags: code-golf, keyboard, encryption

## Challenge

Given a string with any characters a-z or A-Z, return an 'encrypted' string, where all characters are replaced by the character next to it (assuming a QWERTY keyboard).

- Case (uppercase, lowercase) **does not matter**.
- The input will **only** have characters a-z and A-Z.

Shortest code in bytes wins.

---

## Example Input and Output

`Foo Foo Bar Bar Python` → `Gpp Gpp Nst Nst [uyjpm`

`Case does not matter` → `vSDR fprd mpy ,sYYrT`

Comment: Seems like a subset of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50336/given-an-input-move-it-along-the-keyboard-by-n-characters) challenge.

Comment: Looks fairly nice to me. have a +1 :)

Comment: Well at least Jelly would be non-competing there

Comment: "The input will only have characters a-z and A-Z.": should this also say "and ` `"

Comment: Looks like it's more of a dupe of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111132/fix-my-fat-fingers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒlµØqż“[;,”Fṡ2Zy
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ATQAy///xZJswrXDmHHFvOKAnFs7LOKAnUbhuaEyWnn///8iQ2FzZSBkb2VzIG5vdCBtYXR0ZXIi)**

#### How?

```
ŒlµØqż“[;,”Fṡ2Zy - Main link: string
Œl               - convert to lowercase
  µ              - monadic chain separation
   Øq            - qwerty yield: ["qwertyuiop","asdfghjkl","zxcvbnm"]
      “[;,”      - "[;,"
     ż           - zip: [["qwertyuiop","["],["asdfghjkl",";"],["zxcvbnm",","]
           F     - flatten: "qwertyuiop[asdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,"
            ṡ2   - overlapping pairs: ["qw","we","er","rt","ty","yu","ui","io","op","p[","[a","as","sd","df","fg","gh","hj","jk","kl","l;",";z","zx","xc","cv","vb","bn","nm","m,"]
              Z  - transpose: ["qwertyuiop[asdfghjkl;zxcvbnm","wertyuiop[asdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,"]
               y - translate the lowercased string with that mapping
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 91 bytes:

```
s='qwertyuiop[asdfghjkl;zxcvbnm,  ' 
print(''.join(s[s.index(c)+1]for c in input().lower()))
```

Comment: Can remove two bytes if there is no space in input...